# "Debug location is approximate because the source is not available" in R studio

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to run function to plot graphs in R. But somehow I am getting the error" ggsave(p), p is not found. Called from: grid.draw(plot)".

Does anyone know what to do? I have tried to install packages diveRsity and devtools but it is not working. The same function worked on 2/12/2020 but now it is not working.

```
plotHistFunc<- function(x, na.rm = TRUE){
         x<-group.by(x, TRNO, Date)%>%
         p<-ggplot(subset(x, TRNO == trt), aes(x = Date)),
ggsave(p, filename = paste("Livemass", ".png", sep=""))
}
plotHistFunc(mergebiomas, na.rm = TRUE)
```

> But even with that, I always get this error "Error in ggsave(p) with p not found. In addition, we get Called from:grid.draw(plot).

Comment: you have an extra comma at the end of the `ggplot` command. Remove it, it should work. BTW, you will save empty plot, is it intentional ?

Comment: No, it is not. I have really long code that I could not attach. I could not run it from yesterday. I have installed the required packages but it is not working. I removed the extra comma but it is not working.

Comment: Without having more information on your code, it's hard to help you debug this. BTW, from which package is `group.by` function ?

Comment: Thanks. I used dplyr package for it. @dc37, the function is not working. I changed the environment in R studio and it worked.

Comment: The name of the function is `group_by`.

Comment: Thank you. I even did not notice. It is group_by indeed. Thanks